# Deserializing enum with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a custom `ApiException` class that is used as a global model for exceptions thrown by REST controller.

It looks as follows:

```
@JsonIncludeProperties({"timestamp", "status", "error", "message", "path"})
@JsonPropertyOrder({"timestamp", "status", "error", "message", "path"})
@Data
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {

    private String timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String path;

    public ApiException(HttpStatus status, String message, String path) {
        this.timestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
        this.status = status.value();
        this.error = status.getReasonPhrase();
        this.message = message;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

When testing, I'd like to cast a String JSON response to ApiException to test for the field's values... However, I can't deserialize the JSON. The following exception message is shown:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` from number 400: index value outside legal index range [0..68]
```

It appears that Jackson tries to find an `HttpStatus` enum of ordinal value equal to `400`. But, obviously, `400` is meant to represent the status code `400 Bad Request`. What can I do to tell so to Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Jackson uses the internal integer value of enums to deserialize. You need to create a custom deserializer to tell Jackson to use `HttpStatus`'s  `valueOf()` method.

Personally (and alternatively) I'd avoid coupling a class (whos outer structure (constructor) doesn't match its inner structure (fields)) with its JSON representation. Instead create a plain DTO class to read the JSON and convert that later into your exception class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I've decided to create the DTO as you recommended. I've also previously tried to create a custom deserialization class, but I've been ending up with some different exceptions as well. Anyway, could you please take a look at my solution and see if it looks okay to you?

Answer (score 0):

By the suggestion of @RoToRa, I've created a DTO class (`ApiExceptionDTO`), which is responsible for the representation of `ApiException`. The deserialization is not an issue anymore. Here's how both of the classes look like right now:

- `ApiException`:

```
@Data
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {

    private String timestamp;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String path;

    public ApiException(HttpStatus status, String message, String path) {
        this.timestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
        this.status = status;
        this.error = status.getReasonPhrase();
        this.message = message;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public ApiException(ApiExceptionDTO exceptionDTO) {
        this.timestamp = exceptionDTO.getTimestamp();
        this.status = HttpStatus.valueOf(exceptionDTO.getStatus());
        this.error = exceptionDTO.getError();
        this.message = exceptionDTO.getMessage();
        this.path = exceptionDTO.getPath();
    }
}
```

- `ApiExceptionDTO`:

```
@Data
public class ApiExceptionDTO {

    private final String timestamp;
    private final Integer status;
    private final String error;
    private final String message;
    private final String path;

    public ApiExceptionDTO(ApiException exception) {
        this.timestamp = exception.getTimestamp();
        this.status = exception.getStatus().value();
        this.error = exception.getError();
        this.message = exception.getMessage();
        this.path = exception.getPath();
    }

    public ApiExceptionDTO(String timestamp, Integer status, String error, String message, String path) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.status = status;
        this.error = error;
        this.message = message;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you may need to annotate the constructor with the parameters with [`@JsonCreator`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.15.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html).

Comment: @RoToRa No, it's not neccessary. Jackson detects the all-args constructor and uses it.